# Metric Tensor on Lie Group for Left Invariant Metric

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $Q$ be a biinvariant metric.

If $h$ is any positive definite scalar product on $T_eG$ then we have a left invariant metric $h$ on $G$ :

$$ h_g (dL_g X, dL_g Y) = h(X,Y)$$

Then we have a $Q$-symmetric $P\in Gl(T_eG)$ which is called a metric tensor :
$$ h(X,Y) = Q(PX,Y)$$

I want to know $P$ more details.

**Question 1** : For instance, is it a algebra homomorphism ?

And note that ${\rm ad}\ (Z)^\ast = -P^{-1}\circ {\rm ad}\ (Z)\circ P$. Here ${\rm ad}\ (Z)^\ast$ is adjoint operator :

$$ Q(P\ {\rm ad}\ (Z)^\ast\ X,Y)= h(X,[Z,Y])=-Q([Z,PX],Y)$$

**Question 2** : And I want to prove

$$(\ast)\ {\rm ad}\ (Y)^\ast\ X = -[Y,PX]$$ where for all $Y\in V ,\ X\in T_eK$.

Here $V = \{ Y\in T_eG |\ PY=Y\}$, $[T_eK,V]\subset V$ and $h$ is ${\rm Ad}_GK$-invariant.

(cf. Lemma 22 in Eschenburg's book "Freie isometrische Aktionen auf kompakten Lie-Gruppen mit positive gekrummten Orbitraumen" : ($\ast$) is use to prove Lemma 22, whose
statement is as follows :

Under above assumption, we have $$ h(R(X,Y)X,Y)  = 1/4 |[PX,Y]|^2$$
)

Comment: What do you mean by $ad_Z^\ast$?  Also, do you know of an English translation of the Eschenburg work?  I know Eschenburg and Searle were working on one, but I'm pretty sure they've both moved on to other projects.  I am aware of a summary of the results, in English, on Ziller's webpage.  Finally, I don't have time to write a full answer now, but $P$ is not, in general, an algebra homomorphism.  For example, when doing a Cheeger deformation in the direction of a subgroup $H$, $P$ uniformly shrinks everything in $H$ while leaving the orthogonal complement (w.r.t. $Q$) unchanged...

Comment: Choosing a pair of vectors $x,y$ orthogonal to $H$ for which $[x,y]$ is in $H$ (which can often be done), we get $[Px, Py] = [x,y]$ while $P[x,y] = \lambda [x,y]$ for some $\lambda < 1$.  An explicit example is provided with $G=S^3$, thought of as unit length quaternions and $H = S^1$, thought of as unit length complex numbers.

Comment: You're right. In fact I obtain an Eschenburg's result in German on Ziller's webpage. Also I know that there exists an english summary. But I have no idea about an English translation.